# Android default theme not so "default"?

Tags: android

I'm playing with Android development and making some simple apps. I don't want to specify a theme for my app, I'd like it to use the system one; here I mean that every producer and/or user might choose a theme for the device, and the app should adapt to it, looking "native" everywhere. Coming from desktop development, that makes sense to me. I have an LG p880 with android 4.1.2, and I'm developing command-line only just to have control on such things.
Now, the strange thing: on my device my app has white text on black background, but all the other system apps, and especially Google's ones, are black on white. I suppose my app has the "right" appearance, not having forced one myself. So can it be that all the other apps have a custom theme inside? Does that mean that major app developers, and Google first, don't care about system consistency? Should a developer care as much about presentation as the contents?

Comment: i think default doesn't mean being same on every system, but it is default in system specific manner.

Comment: Indeed, but the problem is, it's not default even on the same device.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to specify a theme for my app, I'd like it to use the system one

There are [several dozen "system ones"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) (see the `Theme_`-prefixed entries). And, at the time of this writing, those don't even include the `Theme.Material` set coming up in the next major Android release (and available for experimentation in the "L" Developer Preview).

> Coming from desktop development, that makes sense to me

Conversely, Web developers would consider a "system one" to be a foreign concept.

> I have an LG p880 with android 4.1.2, and I'm developing command-line only just to have control on such things.

You are certainly welcome to develop "command-line only", but since the theme declaration (and definition, if custom) are in XML, you are welcome to use an IDE.

> I suppose my app has the "right" appearance, not having forced one myself.

There is no "right" appearance.

> So can it be that all the other apps have a custom theme inside?

Many probably do. Others will have chosen a different "system" theme. For example, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 11 or higher in your app, you are getting `Theme.Holo` as the overall default, given that you have not specified something to the contrary. Other apps will use `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`, for example. `Theme.Holo` has a dark background with light text; `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` has a light background with dark text except for the action bar.

> Does that mean that major app developers, and Google first, don't care about system consistency?

No more than most Web developers care about "system consistency".

In part, that's because we went down the path you thought of years ago and rejected it. Device manufacturers would tinker with themes, and then our apps would no longer work well. For example, a manufacturer might decide to have dark text on a light background, inverting what other manufacturers had, and then in cases where we are tailoring our own font colors, we'd be screwed, as our colors wouldn't work right on some devices.

In Android 3.0, Google created the `Theme.Holo` family and said that those themes could not be modified by Google Play ecosystem devices. Instead, a `Theme.DeviceDefault` family was created, where manufacturers *could* tinker. I am not aware of any app that ever chose to use a `Theme.DeviceDefault` theme.

In the new Material Design aesthetic being promoted by Google as part of the next version of Android, things like highlight colors are supposed to vary either by app (for branding) or by content (e.g., choosing hues that work well with the photo we're displaying). And even before Material Design, Google has been taking steps to help make it easier for developers to use a custom color scheme to go along with one of the stock system themes (e.g., Android 4.4 de-emphasizing blue as being a touch highlight color).

Comment: I disagree with some of your concepts. Of course web development is different, but on ONE device there should definitely be a "standard" appearance. Excluding graphic-oriented apps, the 90% of "simple GUI" apps (including Settings, Gmail, etc, etc) should have the same default appearance. At least it's what I expect to not have to adapt to a different look for every app. I'd also expect a system setting to change the system theme, but I can't find it. You say Google introduced the Holo theme as a default to stop the "mess", but what's the point if even they don't use it?

Comment: @m.alessandrini: "but on ONE device there should definitely be a "standard" appearance" -- you are certainly welcome to your opinion. "I'd also expect a system setting to change the system theme, but I can't find it" -- that's because there is none. And even if there were, it would only affect a couple of apps. There are third-party apps for rooted devices that allow you to try to hack a theme change into another app, though I have not tried them. "what's the point if even they don't use it?" -- they do use it. `Theme.Holo` is a family, not a single theme.

Comment: @m.alessandrini: Clarifying that last point, Android also supports the notion of extending a theme through inheritance. Most of the Google proprietary apps do that, so they have a general "holo" look to the widgets, but the color choices are app-specific, and most seem to base their custom theme off of `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`. You are also welcome to look at how the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) apps approach the problem: visit https://android.googlesource.com/ and look at the `platform/packages/apps/*` set of Git repositories.

Comment: "if would only affect a couple of apps" -- maybe because Android was not conceived with a paradigm of consistent look-and-feel from the beginning. I don't want to compare myself to Google, but I don't know if it's good for it. Good practices around desktop systems have been there for decades, and Android is not so different from another OS. And about Google and their default, they set dark holo as default, then constantly use another one. Why? Didn't they like it? Perhaps they should have changed the default instead of having the core apps diverge from it. Who's the default for?

Comment: Google have changed their approach to design since Android came out, yes. When Holo was released with Android 3.0, Android was still strongly influenced by the very dark theming of Android Gingerbread before it. Since then each release has progressively changed the default system to a "lighter" colour scheme. It's probably the result of Google not really having any sort of Design team behind Android for the first few years, but it's also natural that the design continues to evolve over time.